# Exception handling in Scala functional programming

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am going through Functional Programming In Scala ( Author :Paul Chiusano and Runar Bjarnarson), found below explanation for not using below total function for exception handling . It says if we are doing a lager computation we should not use, what exactly mean by it . Will you please explain giving a simple example . Thanks !!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Use types to communicate error cases rather than values

Lets a program called `Foo` is using the function `mean`. Unfortunately lets an empty `IndexedSeq` is sent as the argument to the `mean` function. In that case `mean` function would return `onEmpty` which is a Double.

Because `mean` returns a double when `IndexedSeq` is empty, the caller program (Foo program) cannot differentiate between the normal case (where the list is non empty) and the undefined case (where list is empty).

> The problem with the `mean` function it returns `Double` in both undefined case and the normal case when list is non empty.

```
val someList = List.empty[Double]

val meanValue = mean(someList, -1)

if (meanValue == - 1) //undefined case else meanValue
```

The above way of checking the undefined value of the function `mean` is not recommended.

> Author wants to communicate the undefined state by using some type.

Here is how we can do that

```
def mean(list: List[Double]): Option[Double] = {
  if (list.isEmpty) None
  else Some(list.sum / list.length)
}
```

The above `mean` function will return None when undefined case is encountered (list is empty) and does not rely on the unsafe communication of returning a value.

`Foo` program might stop computing when an undefined is return the `mean` function or `Foo` program might take a different branch when encounter by the undefined value (value returned by the `mean` function when list is empty). But `Foo` program has to reply on `onEmpty` value to check for the undefined case.

Comment: Yes I understood of using a generic way of programming(i.e use of Option) , by not relying on programmers input  (like -1, some one can give -5) . But this way can also handle the things . Are you trying to say we should use more generic way of programming to avoid mistakes .

Comment: @PriyaranjanSwain use types to communicate error cases rather than values

Comment: Shouldn't `else list.sum / list.length` be `else Some(list.sum / list.length)` ?

Comment: @RobertUdah yes, fixed it

Comment: @pamu yes your last comment is very powerful and makes me very clear ."use types to communicate error cases rather than values"

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your program can receive a list `List(-2.0, 0.0)`.

```
val list = List(-2.0, 0.0)
val theMean = mean(list, -1.0)

// now I want to handle the error case
if (theMean == -1.0)
  println("mean can't be computed!") // wrong!
```

If `mean` would not take some silly default value but would return an `Option[Double]` or an `Either[String,Double]` or... it is no longer possible to make such a mistake.

Comment: Yes !! now i am clear .pamu has given a statement which is clearly matching with your example i.e "use types to communicate error cases rather than values"